# How to estimate piece-wise smooth fit to a noisy mask?

Tags: algorithms

I have a binary mask that originated from a piece-wise smooth curve. Each underlying curve segment is smooth, but connections between segments may or may not be smooth.
The mask is noisy so it might contain several pixels around the underlying curve. Image below shows an example of such input:
[image: input mask]
I want to estimate a fit to the underlying curve, given this input without any other prior knowledge, that will be able to provide both smooth and non-smooth connections.

I tried several methods polynomial fit, spline smoothing and non-parameteric regression, but was not able to get to the desired output. 
See below examples to the results I get - these fits both fail to capture the non-smooth connection on the left, as well as to provide a good fit for the "tail" on the right:
[image: current results]
Expected results should behave like the red curve in the image below, where I expect the curve at location 1 to be non-smooth and at location 2 to be smooth.
[image: expected results]

I'd be happy to get a reference to a suitable algorithm.

P.S.
I posted this on stackoverflow and was advised to post it here, so sorry for the duplicate from there.

Comment: This question can be relevant for CS but you should remove the part about python/numpy. The point is some people may not know python but very efficient algorithms to your problem, just let them a chance to understand your problem and help you. You should also delete your post from stackoverflow to prevent any doublon.

Comment: Great, if you can also precise what type of curve can be expected. Your example shows that last segment is a parametric curve that cannot be described by a $y=f(x)$. Can the curve make a loop ? Do you know the number of segments ?

Comment: Indeed we cannot assume it can be described by y=f(x). Number of segments is unknown in advance. It may or may not form a loop.